# Distinguish words between delimiters [[ ]] and [[ ]]s in python

Tags: python, string

I want to find single and plural words between delimiters [[ ]] inside a text for example:

```
"I have a red [[pen]], two blue [[pen]]s, two black [[pencil]]s and a green [[pencil]]"
```

should be

```
['pen', 'pen', 'pencil', 'pencil']
```

and another list showing that which one is single for example zero for single and 1 for plurals:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

I know that using the following code I can extract the former list:

```
re.findall(r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', str)
```

But I can't find a way to produce second array or any other approach to identify which one is single or plural. Any idea?

Comment: Look for `]]` followed by a plural ending.  Granted, this does *not* handle certain irregular plurals, such as "radii" for "radius", or "goose" for "goose".

Comment: @Prune maybe a better way is to look for the absence of " a "

Comment: @drooze: keying on `a` covers this example, but hardly generalizes to open discourse.

Comment: @Prune Are you saying Drooze is singular, and so is an example? :)

Comment: `str` is built-in function in Python. You shouldn't use as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to change your regex to include a second capturing group for `s?`.

```
s = "I have a red [[pen]], two blue [[pen]]s, two black [[pencil]]s and a green [[pencil]]"
pat = r"\[\[(.*?)\]\](s?)"
matches = re.findall(pat, s)
print(matches)
#[('pen', ''), ('pen', 's'), ('pencil', 's'), ('pencil', '')]
```

As you can see, the elements in `matches` are tuples. Now just use a list comprehension and check the second element of each tuple for `'s'`.

```
myList = [1 if m[1] else 0 for m in matches]
print(myList)
#[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Obviously this only works for plurals that end in `'s'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check outside the brackets to find plural values:

```
import re
s= "I have a red [[pen]], two blue [[pen]]s, two black [[pencil]]s and a green [[pencil]]"
final_results = [[i[:-2], 0] if not i.endswith('s') else [i[:-3], 1] for i in re.findall('(?<=\[\[)[a-zA-Z]+\]\]s*', s)]
words = [a for a, _ in final_results]
indices = [b for _, b in final_results]
```

Output:

```
['pen', 'pen', 'pencil', 'pencil']
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

`word_string.split(']]')` gives a list of string portion going from each `]]` to the next.

`i.startswith('s')` gives a boolean indicating whether the portion `i` starts with s.

Casting this as `int` gives 1 if it starts with 's' and 0 if it doesn't.

`[int(i.startswith('s'))   for  i in word_string.split(']]') ]` gives a list of `0`s and `1`s indicating whether each portion after each `]]` starts with 's'. Since, given a particular word, you want to know whether the next portion starts with 's', you need to shift this over one. This can be done with `[1:]`.

So, as a one-liner:

`[int(i.startswith('s'))   for  i in word_string.split(']]') ][1:]`

This assumes that words are plural if and only if they end with 's'.